# getElementById vs. using the id name

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have found that I don't need use `document.getElementById` to get the an element, I can use like this:

```
<div id="observer1"></div>
```

Then i can access like a variable:

```
console.log(observer1);
```

Why should I use the `document.getElementById` if I can access directly?
I had never heard that this was possible, is there any side-effect, is this supported in all browsers?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking this `$("#observer1")` vs `document.getElementById('observer1')`

Comment: No, i meant accessing literally like a variable "observer1"

Comment: can you create a working copy?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/218196)

Comment: It's simply not possible to declare a html element with a certain id value, and log it in javascript by using its Id name. You use `document.getElementById` to get the DOM element, which has certain properties depending on the html tag.

Comment: @Momenator: Are you saying this doesn't log the element for you? https://jsfiddle.net/kf9jua5c/

Comment: @FelixKling wow i didnt know you could even do that. Turns out you can actually do that.

Comment: @Momenator—consider deleting your comment then.

Answer (score -3):

Using `console.log(observer1)` just outputs the whole element. You have no control over it. You can't adjust properties, attributes or assign values. There is almost no practical use for doing it that way.

Comment: Can you give an example? observer1 and document.getElementById("observer1"); looks like the same object for me

Comment: What exactly should that jsfiddle prove?

Comment: How to manipulate an element. All you can do with your example is simply log the entire thing to the console.

Comment: ...so https://jsfiddle.net/u7d733s0/1/ doesn't work in your browser?

Comment: This answer seems to miss the point of the question.